# How to delete a tilde (~) folder?

Tags: shell, filenames, rm

I need to delete a "~" folder in my home directory.

I realize now that `rm -R ~` is a bad choice.

Can I safely use `rm -R "~"`?

Comment: I think it is, but to be safe, you could `cd` in, verify the contents, `rm` everything inside, then `cd ..` And `rmdir` the now-empty folder. This assumes `rmdir` will refuse to remove a non-empty dir, which I assume your home directory is.

Comment: There's a question like this for every funky char...

Comment: @don_crissti yes, but I really wanted to be sure so I don't delete my entire home directory. ^_^

Comment: @AdamThompson Just test it out first: `echo rm ~` vs `echo rm "~"`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In theory yes. In practice usually also yes. If you're calling a shell script or alias that does something weird, then maybe no.

You could use `echo` to see what a particular command would be expanded to by the shell:

```
$ echo rm -R ~
rm -R /home/frostschutz
$ echo rm -R "~"
rm -R ~
```

Note that `echo` removes the `""` so you should not copy-paste what it prints. It just shows that if you give `"~"`, the command literally sees `~` and not the expanded `/home/frostschutz` path.

If you have any doubt about any command, how about starting out with something that is less lethal if it should go wrong? In your case you could  start out with renaming instead of deleting it outright.

```
$ mv "~" delete-me
$ ls delete-me
# if everything is in order
$ rm -R delete-me
```

For confusing file names that normally shouldn't even exist (such as `~` and other names starting with `~` or , or containing newlines, etc.), it's better to be safe than sorry.

Also consider using tab completion (type `ls ~<TAB><TAB><TAB>`), most shells try their best to take care of you, this also helps avoid mistyping regular filenames.

Comment: The second advice (`mv "~" delete-me` etc.) is excellent. This is really helping to avoid the stress of a mistyped/misunderstood command.

Comment: Also found the `mv "~" delete-me` advice really useful.

Answer (score 10):

As Kalvin Lee mentioned, you can `cd` to the directory and remove its contents, then use `rmdir` to remove the directory.  I recommend this over the `rm -R` approach because you're less likely to fat-finger the command and blow away your home directory.

Generally, you can put things that you don't want the shell to expand in single quotes.  This will remove an empty directory named `~`:

```
rmdir '~'
```

Comment: Not `rmdir`. OP is clear that this directory isn't empty yet, which is why he's using `rm -R`.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to frostschutz's double quotes method, and Andy's simple quote one, there are also the shorter:

```
rm -r \~
```

and the relative path one:

```
rm -rf ./~
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this has been answered already, but I always use `mc` - Midnight Commander to delete awkward files that I am too afraid in attempting to delete.  It is a "GUI" like interface where you simply highlight the file you want to delete, and delete it.